# change type of array

Tags: c#, arrays, object, reflection

is it possible to change type of whole array for example, I have:

```
object[] array;
```

and I wanna have:

```
MyObject[] array;
```

array contains only items of type MyObject but I can see it only as type object[]
this wouldnt be problem if I dont wanna save this array throught reflection to my object which looks like:

```
class MyArrayObject
{
   public MyObject[] objects {get; set;} 
}
```

so if I use reflection - `MyArrayObject.GetType().GetProperty("objects").SetValue(array)` - I get exception because array if `object[]` type not `MyObject[]` - is it possible to change type of array so I can add it through reflection to desired property?

Reason I have `object[]` not `MyObject[]` array is, that I wanna add new item into array, so I need to resize it or put to list - and then it changes to object[]
array is not always MyObject[] type - it can be MyObject2, MyObject3 .. anything - I get it through reflection too - so problem is adding item into array whose type is dynamically specified.
Thanks!

Comment: could [`CType(exp,type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb(v=vs.100).aspx) be what you want? Just suggesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Reason I have object[] not MyObject[] array is, that I wanna add new item into array, so I need to resize it or put to list

That sounds like a reason to use `List<MyObject>` to start with. Generally prefer lists over arrays.

> is not always MyObject[] type - it can be MyObject2, MyObject3 .. anything

Sounds like a good place to use generics then. If you really need to use reflection, you can always use [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx) with the right element type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a direct way but as a kind of workaround u can iterate through all objects and cast each one to MyObject and add the casted object to a collection.  I know that this is not the best solution and the performance is also not so good, but as i said it's just a workaround. :)

Answer (score 0):

using LINQ

```
array.Cast<MyObject>() // cast every element to MyObject
```

or

```
array.OfType<MyObject>() // filters all MyObject elements
```

then call    .ToArray() method if you want to keep array type

Not very good in general, but simplest way to understand and support